# Javascript mouse events after mousedown on item (img) not working as expected

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dojo, mouseevent, mousemove

I'm trying to improve my mouse event knowledge so this question is about why what I'm doing isn't working more than whether I could use a drag and drop module.

I'm using Dojo and I've connected to mousedown and mouseup events.  When there is a mousedown event that's not a right click, I set up a connection for mousemove.  On the subsequent mouseup event I disconnect that event.  This is what the code looks like:
EDIT (made what should be a self contained example)

```
obj = {

    init: function(){
        var c;
        dojo.connect(dojo.doc, "mousedown", this, function(evt){
            this.down(evt);
            if(evt.button != dojo.mouseButtons.RIGHT){
                this._isDown = true;
                c = dojo.connect(dojo.doc, "mousemove", this, "drag");
            }
        });
        dojo.connect(dojo.doc, "mouseup", this, function(evt){
            dojo.disconnect(c);

            this._isDown = false;
            this.up(evt);
        });
    },//end init

    drag: function(evt){
        console.log("Mouse drag",evt);
    },

    up: function(evt){
        console.log("Mouse up",evt);
    },

    down: function(evt){
        console.log("Mouse down",evt);
    }
}//end obj
```

EDIT: to try this out, inject dojo on any page (with an img) with the console and then create this obj and run obj.init().  Inject with 1.5:

```
document.documentElement.firstChild
    .appendChild(document.createElement("script"))
    .src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js';
```

It looks symmetric to me and works fine if I click over most of the document.  However if I click on an icon and drag it, the "drag" function is called only once (the connection should have made it so every movement of the cursor called it), and the mouseup event isn't called when I release the mouse.

Then next time I mousedown it overwrites c with a new connection, making it so I can't ever disconnect the previous one and thus what I intended to only be active for dragging becomes a permanent event.

A bad solution I've implemented is disconnecting before connecting in the "mousedown" connection.  That makes sure I don't get permanent calls to "drag" but still leaves me with rogue calls to "drag" until I click again to unset it.

Any tips to why this is happening?

Comment: Never used the dojo library, but it sounds like it might have to do with event bubbling.

Comment: Firefox the drag fires just once, Chrome it fires a few times.  And I wouldn't think event bubbling would affect whether the disconnection worked... the fact that "drag" fired before the mouseup and subsequent disconnect did means to me that c should have the connection in time for the mouseup to disconnect it

Comment: Could you add in the code for this.drag as well?

Comment: Should be enough up there now to test it out easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - apparently Firefox and other browsers have default handling of img clicks so by including dojo.stopEvent(evt) in each event listener it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran in to a problem as this I remember fixing it with a focus()

This seemed to fix my problem in both IE and FF

```
       function mouseOverActive(e)
            {               
                //attach listener to document 
                e = e || event;
                var who = e.target || e.srcElement;
                       overlayEditor.attachListeners($_(who.id),'mouseout',mouseOutActive);
                $_(who.id).focus();
                     overlayEditor.attachListeners($_(who.id),'keydown',keypress);  
                     overlayEditor.attachListeners($_(who.id),'keyup',keyrelease);  
            }

        function mouseOutActive(e)
            {
                //attach listener to document 
                e = e || event;
                var who = e.target || e.srcElement;
                var o = $_(who.id);

                overlayEditor.removeListener(o,'mouseout',mouseOutActive);  
                overlayEditor.removeListener(o,'keydown',keypress);
                overlayEditor.removeListener(o,'keyup',keyrelease); 

                this.sbc_Aternative = false; 
                    visualTextSwitch(o,'off');

                o.blur();
            }
```